# Parts of the code in my answer were removed by another user without explanation. How should I proceed?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

[I *answered*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607703/curl-function-and-array-in-the-url/27608627#27608627) a question and next to it added a piece of code that was in another issue of Stack Overflow putting together the source.

But after a few hours, another user edited my answer twice, apparently trying to improve the indentation and the question.

Up to this point, everything is all right. The problem is that he removed part of the code and did not comment at the time of the issue.

I thought of doing a "rollback", but I did not know if I should do it.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Did he actually make a mistake and deface your post? No need to rollback if you agree with the changes... So you know, that wasn't done by a moderator, he used the same editing privileges you have.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks a lot. Did not change the code's functionality, it just changed the way of doing things. That is before the final result is the same. I think that issue was unnecessarily.

Comment: That edit was done by a gold badge holder for `php`. At a glance, it's an improvement: moving comments around, spacing, slightly different syntax for the calls. Of course you are free to roll it back, but are you sure you don't agree it looks better?

Comment: Note you can "ping" an editor of a post the same way as comment writers, a neat feature. You can use the regular `@..` syntax, and ask for clarification.

Comment: @Jongware thanks a lot. I agree that it was better so, what I do not agree with is the absence of justification or explanation of the improvements that were made.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sometimes users are a little more lazy with the edit reason box than we should be :)

Comment: You can still add a comment and recommend to leave a clarification the next time. Scrolling through his actions I see lots of `add X characters in body`, such as [this fairly massive rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27487534/revisions). I had to look *twice* before finally deciding, yes, it still seems to be the same code. (And it's better!)

Comment: @Jongware I found a review of it in question (not the answer)
apparently he wants to help the OP's question to improve code organization, had not the Intent to fix, it sounds like only encouraging the organization of code. I thanked him and asked him to add a comment. Thanks a lot, problem solved.

Comment: @Jongware [that edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27487534/revisions) is horrible. If Hakre wants to say _"this code is an utter piece of crap that you shouldn't actually use in any way, even though it seems to yield the desired result for this specific case"_ (i.e. don't use substrings for XML parsing), then that user should say so in a comment under the answer, instead of putting a passive-agressive comment in the code in the post. Now an uneducated reader is nothing wiser and will happily copy the code without the comments.

Comment: Looks like they are a serial offender I would **roll back the edit**. Switching around the order doesn't really change anything. In my opinion the editor should leave a comment and suggest improvements, not just go ahead and deface your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *"was in another issue of Stack Overflow"*?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's still your post, so you can decide if you like the changes or not. If you do, keep them. If not, roll it back. Also, consider asking the editor why they made the changes with a comment.

That said, content on Stack Overflow is expected to be community curated (without changing the author's intent, of course), so you shouldn't be too surprised when your post is edited.

Finally, that was done using simple 2K+ editing privileges, that user isn't a diamond moderator.

Answer (score 9):

The only question to ask yourself in this situation is: do you want the answer, as it stands under the edit, to be attributed to *you*? It has your name on it. Everyone will see it as your answer. If that is not acceptable, roll it back without hesitation.

This way of thinking about the matter has served me well on all occasions. I am happy and grateful to let someone correct my spelling or fix a broken link. But I do not, under any circumstances, let anyone put words in my mouth or change my coding style.