# Old answer significantly edited by other user

Tags: discussion

This question is similar to this one ([Answer edited by other user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280991/answer-edited-by-other-user)), but the problem is less 'clear cut', at least to me.

I have a post, that has been around for *ages*, (and I had been thinking that I should update it a bit, but hadn't), to find that someone has significantly changed the answer... and not particularly for the better (that's just my opinion, of course):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2590049/revisions

I do not particularly like the edits that have been made, as it adds lots of unnecessary words (again IMHO). There is also some information given regarding "Gmap4rails" that is quite beyond the question, and is clearly "tampering" with the answer... and yet was let through the revision process. That said, it **is** a legitimate attempt at providing a more clear answer.

What is the best course of action here?

Comment: If I were you I'd just roll it back. It's your answer after all.

Comment: `... and yet was let through the revision process.` - the user in question has >2k rep, so there is no review or other form of process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel the edits don't add improvement then roll back.
Or, as advised in the other Meta question you linked to, you can ping the user, although I'm not sure that would be useful, either you agree with the edits or not.

I'm not familiar with the code in your answer, so cannot comment technically, but it looks to me like a good bit of additional info - explanations, more code, and more descriptions about the additional code.
Do you not feel this is good info for others seeing the answer? Is the additional code not valuable to the question or perhaps useful to users with *similar* issues/questions?

Your answer has 200 upvotes, and the question 57, with some 73,609 views in 5 years, and while your answer having little content may be *enough*, it's arguable the edit adds some juicy info to what is a fairly popular question.

Site rules/guidelines:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: Just to clarify, those edits have happened in the last few days. No votes have arrive since then. You have answered though... I will spend some time elaborating & revising the answer

Comment: @cmroanirgo Edited my answer to remove wrong info. Cheers.